# Jar cant' find main class

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I built a jar file and then tried to run the jar file and I getting the infamous

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

I have things in a directory tree.
`mainFolder` contains `manifestFolder`, containg my manifest.
Also under the `mainFolder` there is my `source` directory which is down a couple of levels.
source =  `level1.level2.mainPackage`  directories -3 levels
main class is in package and folder - `mainPackage`

manifest contents :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.1-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: level1.level2.mainPackage.MainApp
Class-Path: lib/appframework-1.0.3.jar lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

I build the jar with this command

```
jar -cfmv NewTool.jar manifestFolder\MANIFEST.MF level1\level2\dynamictnd
```

Comment: Can we see your code for the main class?

Comment: @BitNinja suppose it's "HelloWorld" - does it matter ?

Comment: What matters is: the code used to run the jar file, and maybe a screenshot of the directory tree (the description is unclear).

Comment: What is your main class name, and what does your JAR look like in 7-Zip (or equivalent)?

Comment: We also need to see the *complete* stacktrace and error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jar command appears to be incorrect.

```
jar -cfmv NewTool.jar manifestFolder\MANIFEST.MF level1\level2\dynamictnd
```

includes the `dynamictnd` folder of `level2` (only). You need something like

```
jar -cfmv NewTool.jar manifestFolder\MANIFEST.MF level1
```

to get everything under `level1`. Finally, examine the jar file with `jar tvvf` (or winzip) and make sure it's got your `Main-Class` (as posted, it can't because your main-class is under "level1\level2\mainPackage").

Comment: I tried the different command and then print out the contents and the main class is in the jar file.     When I type the jar tvvf NewJar.jar it outputs this                                                                                                                                                                Test Project/bin/MainTest.class.     How do I specify this path in the Manifest. Do the / get replaced by . ?

Comment: @user3470688 They do, but it must match your actual package structure. I think you actually wanted `jar -cfmv NewTool.jar manifestFolder\MANIFEST.MF "Test Project\bin"` but since your example was in a package I assumed your real code was too.

Comment: Yea, whatever I need to specify to get this to work. I tried all sorts of variations in the manifest but no luck.

Comment: What if I have no package name at all. DO I use defautl

Comment: You would use `Main-Class: MainTest` and the `jar` command from my last comment. If that's what you mean by *default*.

Comment: THank you for helping. Still no luck! Manifest:Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.1-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: MainTest
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Comment: jar -cfmv NewTool.jar manifestDir\MANIFEST.MF "Test Project\bin"

Comment: :\Users\Ethan\workspace>jar tvvf NewTool.jar
    0 Fri Jan 23 21:43:44 EST 2015 META-INF/
  138 Fri Jan 23 21:43:44 EST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    0 Fri Jan 09 21:10:08 EST 2015 Test Project/bin/
 1279 Fri Jan 09 21:13:38 EST 2015 Test Project/bin/MainTest.class

Comment: C:\Users\Ethan\workspace>java -jar NewTool.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class MainTest

Comment: You didn't run `jar -cfmv NewTool.jar manifestFolder\MANIFEST.MF "Test Project\bin"` It has to match exactly. and your package name can't include a space... but since you have no package, `MainTest.class` should be at the "root" of the jar.

Comment: There are all of the commands I entered and still errors. I am getting frustrated. Directory of C:\Users\Ethan\workspace

1/23/2015  09:13 PM    <DIR>          .
1/23/2015  09:13 PM    <DIR>          ..
7/26/2013  06:39 PM    <DIR>          .metadata
1/23/2015  09:08 PM    <DIR>          ManifestDir
1/23/2015  09:43 PM             1,460 NewTool.jar
7/26/2013  06:39 PM    <DIR>          Test Project
1/01/2014  02:49 PM    <DIR>          UDP
              1 File(s)          1,460 bytes

Comment: a slightly different er
C:\Users\Ethan\workspace>jar -cfmv NewTool.jar manifestDir\MANIFEST.MF "Test Project\bin"
added manifest
adding: Test Project/bin/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: Test Project/bin/MainTest.class(in = 1279) (out= 801)(deflated 37%)

C:\Users\Ethan\workspace>java -jar NewTool.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class level1.level2.mainPackage.MainAppror

Comment: I figure out that last one,but I am back oManifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.1-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: MainTest.class
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Comment: C:\Users\Ethan\workspace>jar -cfmv NewTool.jar manifestDir\MANIFEST.MF "Test Project"\bin
added manifest
adding: Test Project/bin/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: Test Project/bin/MainTest.class(in = 1279) (out= 801)(deflated 37%)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69489/discussion-between-elliott-frisch-and-user3470688).

Comment: C:\Users\Ethan\workspace>java -jar NewTool.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class MainTest.class